# Creating javascript condition from server-side property in ASP.NET Webforms

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms

I was wondering what is the most correct and elegant way of creating a JS condition based on a server-side property.

I thought about the following options:

```
<% if (obj.Prop == true) { %>
    // Code A
<% } else { %>
    // Code B
<% } %>
```

Or this option:

```
var clientProp = <%= obj.Prop.ToString().ToLower() %>;

if (clientProp) {
    // Code A
} else {
    // Code B
}
```

What do you think is better?

Comment: Second is better, it requires less typing, also you can write tests  more easily latter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are only some exceptional cases which are correct and elegant at the same time.
I think you should consider for efficiency.

Your 1st method is more efficient since java script code will be less but at the cost of maintainability.

Your second method may be more maintable but at the cost of efficiency(more download time for more code.).